# Radio button style zoom inconsistent size/place?

Tags: css, google-chrome, zooming

I have a situation here where i have a radio button which i customized for the styling, then when by accident i zoom out to 90% i saw that the radio button and it inner circle style look odd. look at below example(i created similar situation) on 90% on chrome the inner circle looks a little bit on bottom left (not exactly in the middle)

```css
.radiobutton {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #40a9c7;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checked{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 4px;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #40a9c7;
}
```

```html
<div class="radiobutton">
    <div class="checked"></div>
</div>
```

I don't have any idea what might be the cause here, does it lost precision or something? any help or direction or workaround would be appreciated